# Laravel のルートについて

Tags: laravel

例えば下記の様なルートが定義されています。

```
Route::get('/profile/edit', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile/update', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
Route::delete('/profile/delete', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
```

Formからupdateやdestoryは出来ますが、ブラウザのurlに直接 `http://localhost/profile/update` とすると落ちてしまいます。

patchメソッドのところをgetでアクセスしているので当然なのですが、エラーを出さないでprofileページなどに戻すことは可能ですか？
（実際にupdateの処理をしたいわけではありません）

Answer (score 1):

フォールバックルートというのがあります

https://readouble.com/laravel/10.x/ja/routing.html

```php
Route::fallback(function(){
    return redirect(route('profile')); 
});
```

こういう感じで書いておけば（ルート名は適宜変えてください），存在しないルートにアクセスしたときに profile にリダイレクトさせられます．